How to have an app window not take away focus like in Windows 11 emoji app
Let's say you have Notepad open in Windows 11. You hit Win+. shortcut to open the emoji app. Click on an item and it pastes it in wherever your | symbol is in your Notepad.
Essentially we have a window we can control like any normal piece of UI, without removing focus from the previously focused window (Notepad in our case).
How would I be able to replicate this behavior in Electron?

Extra note:
This is something that could potentially be achieved by making the app window unfocusable and adding in a bunch of code that would process global inputs, but that would result in quite an overengineered solution. I'm curious if there's anything out of the box that would support this behavior.
Any help much appreciated!

take a look at this.
